# Which query is faster to perform in mongodb: using $in range or pair of $gte and $lte?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm interesting in performance issue. Suppose I have a collection with field `ref` (represented in each document). What I want is to find all documents in specific range (for example, [1-1,000,000]. Is there any difference in the following queries in terms of db performance

`db.test.find({"ref": {"$gte":1, "$lte": 1000000}})` and 
`db.test.find({"ref": {"$in": [1,2,3, ..., 1000000]}})`

Additional question is about memory consumption. Which query is more suitable in this case if I use pymongo driver?

Comment: You would have to measure with your dataset, but common sense would say that two comparison operations is significantly faster than searching for a value in an array that contains million elements. The same goes for memory consumption: not having an array is smaller than an array with million elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference, since range query will be transformed internally to regex query, and if there is an index on 'ref' field, covered query will be evaluated almost in no-time.

Query where you pass a list of elements is a bit heavy, so it will take more time to send it over the wire, after which MongoDb engine will have to evaluate comparison of each array element with each document property.

Comment: A [range query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-ranges) and a [`regex` match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) are separate concepts. A range query is definitely **not** transformed into a regex query; perhaps you are conflating this with the *bounds* of index values that will be compared based on a range query. Assuming an appropriate index, a query for a large range of values is certainly going to be faster and more efficient than passing (and looking up) a million individual values.